# Reading JQuery.ajax URL call data in VB .Net Code behind

Tags: vb.net, jquery

I wish to read the value of a text box in a .aspx page and save it every so many seconds.

I have found the following code at:
[How to implement an "Auto Save" or "Save Draft" feature in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889004/how-to-implement-an-auto-save-or-save-draft-feature-in-asp-net)

I modified it for my purposes a little bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.setInterval(saveDraft, 5000);
    });        
    function saveDraft() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SaveDraft.aspx",
            data: ({
            draftData: $("#<%=dataTextBox.ClientID %>").val()                    
            }),
            success: function(response) {
                alert('saved draft');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Let's say dataTextBox is a textbox defined in the `.aspx` page. I have the code behind in VB .Net . But I do not know how I can get the value of the text box text field in the code behind. I suppose  I am passing it through the line

```
draftData: $("#<%=dataTextBox.ClientID %>").val()
```

to `SaveDraft.aspx`.

In `SaveDraft.aspx.vb` I have:

```
Public Partial Class SaveDraft
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' What should go here to read dataTextBox.text?
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to read the value of dataTextBox by the following line of code in Page_Load

```
 Dim testStr As String = Request.Form("draftData")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call a pagemethod from the jQuery, passing the data along with it.

A good example of this can be found here:

http://trentgardner.net/net/asp-net-webmethods-with-jquery-and-ajax/