# How to call web method on change event of textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events, webmethod

I have a text box. On its input I want to save its data like sticky Note I mean Auto Save textbox in asp.net.

My front end code is :

```
<textarea id="txtClientArea" runat="server" class="scfMultipleLineTextBox" cols="20" rows="4" onchange="onTextChange" >
```

My javascript Web method is:

```
function onTextChange(data) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "StickyNote.aspx/SaveData",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "data": data }),
            datatype: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("C# method calling : " + response.d);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Code behind method is :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void SaveData(string data)
{
    User currentUser = Sitecore.Context.User;
    if (currentUser != null)
    {
        currentUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty("StickyNote", data);
    }
}
```

How do I make the textbox data auto save?

Comment: This exemple above works? Whant's the issue?

Comment: it is not working when i put some values in textarea javascript method is not calling

Comment: Refer the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889004/how-to-implement-an-auto-save-or-save-draft-feature-in-asp-net

Comment: @neenumariya mostly i want something like this but it send request after each 5 seconds but i want to send this request after any change not after each 5 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
$('#<%=txtClientArea.ClientID%>').on('change',function () {
    var data = encodeURIComponent($(this).text());                
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "StickyNote.aspx/SaveData",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "data": data }),
        datatype: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("C# method calling : " + response.d);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it is throwing an error :

TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
error source line:
$('textarea').live('change', function () {

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? You should note that as of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. The alternative is the `.on()` to attach event handlers.

Comment: i'm using :
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the correct method `.on()`, give that a try, should work.